# Factorising equation with power 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When you have polynomial for example $x^2 + 10 x + 25$ and you are asked to factorise, I know that two numbers that multiply to make $25$ and add to make $10$ are $5$ and $5$ and you take out the $x$.

So it becomes $(x + 5) (x + 5)$.

However when you have a polynomial like $x^3 - 4x^2 + 3x$ what is a rule you can use for this ? I know that this becomes $x(x-1) (x-3) = 0$ to find $x$ but I would not know how to do this and would put in unnecessary effort. So is there a rule to factorise these types of polynomials ?

Comment: In the particular example here (and any cubic polynomial with zero constant term), we can see immediately that all terms contain a factor of $x$, so that $x^3 - 4 x^2 + 3 x = x(x^2 - 4 x + 3)$, which reduces the problem to factorizing a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: You can see different methods for factoring  polynomial at :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the answer is yes, but extremely complicated.  For most problems you'd face, the [rational roots theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) should suffice if you can't see a clear way to factor.

In this case, we see $x=0$ is a possible root, and it is, thus

$$x^3 - 4 x^2 + 3 x = x(x^2 - 4 x + 3)$$

And the rest is a quadratic.